# NSDateFormatter dateFromString crash

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, nslocale

`Crashlytics` service report some crash (about 30 crash / 18 users for 1000 sessions)

Here my code :

```
var brutDate: String = ""
brutDate <- map["send_date"]

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(brutDate)! // here is the crash (this is line 42)
```

Crashlog is :

```
Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x170422a80 :: NSOperation 0x170257190 (QOS: UTILITY)
0  AppName        0x100085f84 specialized SNotification.mapping(Map) -> () (SNotification.swift:42)
1  AppName        0x100084ff4 SNotification.mapping(Map) -> () (SNotification.swift:29)
2  AppName        0x100085a78 protocol witness for Mappable.mapping(Map) -> () in conformance SNotification (SNotification.swift:29)
```

In this case brutDate value is `2017-01-31 20:02:08`

I'm not able to make app crash one my mobiles...

EDIT : I'm in France and app is deployed for Canada, is there a `Locale` problem ?

Comment: Any exclamation mark can crash the app. Learn how to handle optionals safely.

Comment: why don't you use if let or guard to handle the optional downcasting..??

Comment: Yes I'm aware this is an other problem. If date variable is not set, date will be nil.

Comment: but remember - brutDate may be non-nil, and still not generate a valid Date

if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(brutDate)
{
// do stuff with date
}
else
{
// oops - display error
}

Comment: In my case I know that brutDate can't be nil. Just an important information : i'm in France and app is deployed for Canada. If there a locale problem ?

Answer (score 4):

There probably is a locale problem, or a device problem. If the device has 24 hour time set to off, then that will be used by your formatter, rewriting the format string you have supplied. You can reproduce this locally by setting your time format to 12 hours.

To prevent this, use the `en_US_POSIX` locale for the date formatter, which will make it use the format you have supplied without modification:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

This is explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).

In any case you're still better off not using `!` and logging and error or providing a sensible default value if one can't be recovered from the string.